# Unity Непонятные просадки FPS на Android

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android, mobile-development

При запуске игры на Android отображается около 40 фпс, но через некоторое время (от 1-2 секунд до нескольких минут) фпс выравнивается и становится стабильными 60 (телефон как раз поддерживает 60 герц). Также если свернуть и снова открыть игру, то получаю обратно 40 фпс. Даже если отключить все объекты и cкрипты, оставив лишь камеру и счётчик фпс, то ситуация остается ровно такой же (даже отключал сам GUI). Пересмотрел множество решений по оптимизации и не одна из них не решила проблему. Заметил интересное совпадение, если подключить зарядное устройство и сразу же отключить, то фпс сразу выравнивается до 60.

Profiler:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Телефон: Redmi Note 7.
Тестировал на 4-х разных телефонах (из них на 3-х была такая проблема) и лишь на более мощном с герцовкой в 120 оставались стабильные 120.
Установлено ограничение Application.targetFrameRate = 280;

Настройки проекта.
На всех статичных обьектах установлено Static.
Shader: Mobile/Difuse, Mobile/.
Graphics API: перепробовал все возможные (OpenGLES 3, OpenGLES 2, Vulkan).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй поставить галочку Development Build, может сработает

Comment: Так когда я получал данные с Profiler, то они и были с Development Build. В нём то же самое